# Can the AppBar go to the bottom of screen instead of top? (Gluon)

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I want to have the toolbar/AppBar at the bottom of the view instead of the top. Is there a way for me to do that? Here is an image for reference. Thanks.

[Image of ideal bottom AppBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0JaP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `AppBar` is currently only shows up on top of the views. It should be possible to use `BottomNavigation` to some extent to emulate the functionality you have in mind.